# preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

Tags: php, arrays, regex

array search is returning error.

Suppose i have an arrays like so ---

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [category] => phone cases
        [country] => sweden
        [sale_price] => 90,99
        [price] => 120
        [currency] => sek
        [vat] => 19
        [product_name] => "iphone 6 plus" case transparent
        [description] => transparent case for iphone 6 plus
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13
        [category] => shoes
        [country] => sweden
        [sale_price] => 180,99
        [price] => 200
        [currency] => sek
        [vat] => 19
        [product_name] => blue platform shoes
```

Now i am trying to search something from this array, basically i am trying to find it from the $all_data,  **['product_name']** field

```
$data = 'plus'; // what i want to search
$search = $this->my_array_search($all_data, $data);


function my_array_search($array, $string) {
    $pattern = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_quote($string));
    return array_filter($array, function ($value) use($pattern) {
        return preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $value) == 1;
    });
}
```

but it is keep returning me an error --

> preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given

What i am doing wrong, do any one knows how to solve this problem !!

Comment: Items of your top-level array are arrays, not strings.

Comment: @MaratTanalin than how should i search from an array

Comment: `$value` is an array, `$value['product_name']` is the string in that array that you seem to be interested in.

Comment: @Sammitch yes, than how should i suppose to search from the field `['product_name']` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're filtering a [two dimensional array](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp), an array containing arrays.

The right regex function for searching an array would be [preg_grep()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). It returns an array of matches.
(don't forget to specify the delimiter with `preg_quote`)

```
$data = 'plus'; // what i want to search
$search = my_array_search($all_data, $data);

function my_array_search($array, $string)
{
    $ret = false;
    $pattern = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_quote($string, '/'));
    foreach($array AS $k => $v) {
      $res = preg_grep('/' . $pattern . '/', $v);
      if(!empty($res)) $ret[$k] = $res;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

[See demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/468671). Result array would consist of: `key` => `array(matches)`

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["product_name"]=>
    string(32) ""iphone 6 plus" case transparent"
    ["description"]=>
    string(34) "transparent case for iphone 6 plus"
  }
}
```

To only search a certain column if PHP version >= 5.5 try using [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
print_r(preg_grep('/plus/', array_column($all_data, 'product_name')));
```

Use `i` [modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) if you want to match case insensitive and add [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it - as someone pointed out, you have a nested array, one level deep.

```
$data = 'plus'; // what i want to search
$search = $this->my_array_search($all_data, $data);


function my_array_search($array, $string) {
    for ($i=0; $i< count($array); $i++)
    {
        $pattern = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', preg_quote($string));
        return array_filter($array[$i], function ($value) use($pattern) {
            return preg_match('/' . $pattern . '/', $value) == 1;
        });
    }

}
```

This can be improved upon to look into each value and check if it too is an array, and then recursed into - if thats something you're thinking could be useful in the future as well but you would need to work out how you are collecting matches in a better way